# Create set of drones to fly in patterns

Tags: quadcopter

How would one go about making a number of drones fly in a preset pattern or formation. for example have them rotating around a point.

something like this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShGl5rQK3ew

Comment: Welcome to Robotics, Tommy. As it currently
stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complete answer to this question would be very very long I'll attempt to answer it in generally high-level lines. If you wish to know specifics ask several more concise questions.

1. You need to create the drones. The drones need to be controllable and stable. Quadcopters are usually OK, octocopters are more stable/easier to control. Larger ones are more stable but have less maneuver capabilities.
2. You need a localization system so each drone knows it's position and orientation in a fixed coordinate system. This can be obtained in a quite large number of ways. Usually orientation is obtained using IMU and the position can be obtained via GPS (or dGPS for higher precision if possible), some sound-based system (using TDOA method or similar) or some visual systems for example. Another approach would be to fully localize only one drone and then use some system to find the relative positions of other drones with respect to that one.
3. After that, you need to produce control sequences to guide the drones along those paths. This can be done from the ground by some wireless control system or can be implemented directly onto the drones.

Given how wide your question is I hope this covers at least some portion of the answer you were looking for.